# understanding the proof of knowledge

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Recently I've been reading the paper [*“A New Family of Implicitly Authenticated Diffie-Hellman Protocols”*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/035.pdf). It's very hard for me to go further. Especially when it comes to the proof of knowledge. Actually, I never meet this concept before.

There are two extended concepts to the proof of knowledge in the paper, i.e. “joint proof of knowledge” and “non-malleable joint proof-of-knowledge”, which are abbreviated to JPOK and NMJPOK respectively in the paper. Can someone help me understand them (in a plain and simple way)?

Comment: Anything in particular remains unclear after reading Wikipedia's entry on [proof of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge)? Or/and Mihir Bellare and Oded Goldreich's reference article: [On Defining Proofs of Knowledge](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-48071-4_28)?

Comment: In your first question, do you mean Zero-Knowledge Proof of Knowledge? or a mere Proof of Knowledge?

Comment: By the paper being linked, it looks like we're talking about Zero-Knowledge Proofs of Knowledge.